# CSS placing an absolute div beside another div (pure CSS popover)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar with a user profile picture (pink color). When the viewer hover on the image, a `div` (blue color) appears and it contains user details. Basically, I want an *absolute positioned* `div` appear **next to** its sibling.

[image: absolute div beside another div]

It is functionally a popover, but I want to do it with pure CSS, is it possible?

I am using boostrap 4, it will be nice if the suggestion can co-exists with Bootstrap CSS. It will be awesome if the `div` can have an *arrow* associate with it.

My code is:

```
<div>
    <div><figure class="figure"><img ... /></figure></div>
    //css-popover
    <div class="css-popover">User detail: ... bla bla bla ...</div>
</div>
```

I tried to search in Stackoverflow, most of the question is related to `float` div and makes it *beside*, but I want something `absolute positioned`, and display *on top* of the body.

---

**Update:**

Most of the suggestions provided fulfill part of the requests. The suggested `.css-popover` *width* and *height* are bounded by the parents, but I wish the popover **dimension be independent** from the parent, i.e. just "popup" and it doesn't "change" the layout beneath.

[image: popup]

And when the popup appear, it doesn't change the parent height too. I wish the sidebar "icon" (light pink icons) stay in place whenever a popup appear.

If it is not possible with CSS, then I just go for JS solution...

You can try your luck here. **https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/13/**

(Note: the user content is long, so it height usually will exceed the profile image's height)

---

**Update 2:**
Thanks to @Gezzasa, his solution is working. ^_^

Guy, this is the working example of **pure CSS popover**! Amazing!

**https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/15/**

Thanks, guy...

Comment: yan please add css and provide jsfidle...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/3/ yeah yeah... i have create a jsfiddle... you guys are fast, while i am creating this fiddle, 3 answers + fiddle were created.. amazing...

Comment: I expect no less than 3 carats https://jsfiddle.net/nohno2bd/10/

Comment: Edited the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nohno2bd/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/dqwtvf1g/3/

hover set on the parent and set the child to display: block;

You'll need to add the absolute position etc but this is how I've done it before.

```
.figure {background-color: #fff; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
.css-popover {display: none; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #fff;}
.parent:hover .css-popover{display: block;}
```

UPDATE: Made the parent display: inline-block but you can always just add a width.

UPDATE2: I've added some css animation for you as well.

UPDATE3: Edited your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/15/

Comment: hmmm... but I wish the popover appear *beside* (next-to) the figure... not inside the figure, and with self dimension (*width* & *height*)

Comment: Okay fine...I'll do your code for you. I edited my Update 3 URL. it's next to the image now but the width I couldn't change due to the bootstrap column width. You'll need to play around with that if you're not 100% happy.

Comment: Can you update your comment with the latest updated fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/15/ (will be beneficial for everyone)

Comment: @BooYanJiong I have done so, glad It's working for you! Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

This is one pure CSS solution.. But i recomend using JS

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.figure {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}

.figure+.css-popover {
  height: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.figure+.css-popover::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -10px;
}

.figure:hover+.css-popover,
.css-popover:hover {
  width: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}

.clearfic,
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <figure class="figure"></figure>
  <div class="css-popover">User detail: ... bla bla bla ...</div>
</div>
<div>Some content</div>
```

**EDIT** : Added arrow

Comment: I tried your solution, but the `.css-popover` still bound to the parent *width*... I wish the `.css-popover` can have self  dimension, not limited by the parent, probably an 'absolute positioned' popup with self width and auto-height...

Answer (score 1):

hi you can try something like this

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-con">
  <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" alt="" />
    <div class="info-con">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam modi, distinctio nostrum reprehenderit explicabo amet exped
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.img-con
{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  position: relative;
}
.info-con
{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #5C6BC0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  transition:all ease 0.4s;
  padding:3px;
  opacity:0;
}
.info-con::after
{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left:-40px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  height:0;
  border:20px solid transparent;
  border-right-color:#5C6BC0;
}
.img-con:hover .info-con
{
  right:-110%;
  left:auto;
  opacity:1;
}
```

[link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/VWvrxm)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/byanjiong/nohno2bd/13/ I tried it, but the `.info-con` follow the width of its parent, can its width be independent from its parent? And the height of the `.info-con` is limitted by the parent too... hmmm.. any solution for that? Anyway, thank you...

Comment: hi @BooYanJiong you can increse the .info-con height .. try increasing the height

Comment: hmm... but I want the `.info-con` follow the height of the *user profile image*, while the `.popover` have self defined dimension...

Answer (score 0):

Change dimensions as per your need

```css
.popover-container{
  position: relative;
}
.css-popover{
  position: absolute;
}
.css-popover {
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.css-popover:after, .css-popover:before {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.css-popover:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.css-popover:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-top: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class = "popover-container" ><figure class="figure"><img ... /></figure><div class="css-popover">User detail: ... bla bla bla ...</div></div>

    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) With Pure css.

```css
.wrap {
   position: relative;;
}

.im {
   width: 200px;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
}

.css-popover{
   display: none;
}

.im:hover + .css-popover {
   display: block;
}

figure {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="im">
     <figure class="figure"><img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" /></figure>
   </div>
   <div class="css-popover">User detail: ... bla bla bla ...</div>
</div>
```

> 2) With Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.figure img').hover(function(){
  $('.css-popover').css('display','block');
 },function(){
  $('.css-popover').css('display','none');
   })
})
```

```css
.css-popover {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div>
       <figure class="figure"><img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" /></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="css-popover">User detail: ... bla bla bla ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I wish the `css-popover` can align **next** to its sibling, with **height** and **width** independent to its parent. Just like a normal pop-over component, when it appear, it doesn't interrupt the document, but just appear *on top* of the html.